# Order dates in ggplot by month

Tags: r, date

I have `DF$Date` in the as.Date format "yyyy-mm-dd" as shown below. Is there an easy way to get these grouped by month in ggplot?

```
Date
2015-07-30
2015-08-01
2015-08-02
2015-08-06
2015-08-11
2015-08-12
```

I've added a column `DF$Month` as "year Monthname" (e.g. April 2015.)
I'm doing this by `DF$Month<-strftime(DF$Date,format="%B %Y")`

Is there a quick way to factor the month/years so that they are ordinal? 
I used a workaround by formatting using:
`DF$Month<-strftime(DF$Date,format="%Y-%m")` so that the larger numbers are first and subsequently the month number.
This gives the output, which is sortable:

```
DF$Month
"2015-07" 
"2015-08"
```

This output allows me to get this grouping:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/NmV0q.jpg
When using this plot:

```
MonthlyActivity<-ggplot(DF,aes(x=Month, y=TotalSteps))+
  geom_boxplot()
MonthlyActivity
```

Any alternatives so I can use the full month name and still be in the correct time order?

Comment: Why not transform the entire date to a Date-object? (`as.Date(....)`. This will allow ggplot to generate date-scales. Anything else is hard to say without a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: I'm not sure what it is you want. Can you elaborate?

Comment: I've revised my post. Let me know if there are more details to add.

Comment: What are you trying to plot? What do you mean with 'grouped by month'?

Comment: The idea is that I have a bunch of individual date, data points, but would like to create a box plot, aggregating the dates by month.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are probably other solutions, but here is one with full month names as a factor. As you already found out, you need a x variable to group by. We can then treat it as a 'order a factor' problem instead of a date-scale problem.

```
#first, generate some data
dat <- data.frame(date=sample(seq(as.Date("01012015",format="%d%m%Y"),
                           as.Date("01082015", format="%d%m%Y"),by=1),1000,T),
                  value=rnorm(1000))
```

We find the minimum and maximum month, and do some date-arithmetic to allow for all start-days (so that february doesn't get skipped when the minimum date is on the 29th/30th/31st). I used lubridate for this.

```
library(lubridate)
min_month = min(dat$date)-day(min(dat$date))+1
max_month = max(dat$date)-day(max(dat$date))+1
```

We generate a grouping variable. It is a factor with labels like 'January 2015, March 2015'. However, we force the order by creating a sequence (by month) from min date to max date and formatting it in the same way.

```
dat$group <- factor(format(dat$date, "%B %Y"), 
                    levels=format(seq(min_month, max_month,by="month"),
                                                             "%B %Y"))
```

This forces the ordering on the axis:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that levels piece by sequence was what I was missing! It looks like some of the dates in February are off though, resulting in `NA`. I believe the sequencing is looking for end of Feb, how can we account for that?

Comment: Indeed, you were nearly there. Good luck with the project :)

Comment: Edited above, but followup question: It looks like some of the dates in February are off though, resulting in `NA`. I believe the sequencing is looking for end of Feb, how can we account for that?

Comment: Unsure what you mean, and I can't see any edit. Sorry

Comment: I added in the date sequence using `DF$Month2<-factor(format(DF$Date, "%B %Y"),levels=format(seq(min(DF$Date),max(DF$Date),by="month"),"%B %Y"))` However, as the date range extends into `2016-02-01` the result of the code is `NA`

Comment: Currently playing with it. Appears to be an issue when the minimum date is for instance on the 30th (feb gets skipped). Working on solution.

Comment: Looks good! Can you edit the factoring line to replace `min(dat$date)...` with the `min_month` for others.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding

`scale_x_discrete(limits = month.abb)`

so your code would be

`MonthlyActivity<-ggplot(DF,aes(x=Month, y=TotalSteps))+ geom_boxplot()+scale_x_discrete(limits = month.abb)`

you will need `library(dplyr)`